# How to access <content:encoded> with CDATA from RSS feed?

Tags: php, rss, cdata, simplexml

### Problem

If you try to access `<content:encoded>` in a RSS feed the result will be null.

### XML

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
    <channel>
        <item>
        <pubDate>Tue, 16 Jun 2015 14:58:15 +0200</pubDate>
        <title>title</title>
        <link>/your/path/</link>
        <description>description</description>
        <content:encoded>
        <![CDATA[
        <p>content</p>
        ]]>
        </content:encoded>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

### PHP

```
$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($data->channel->item as $item){
    $title = $item->title;
    var_dump($title); //title
    $content = $item->content;
    var_dump($content); //null
}
```

### Question

How can I access content and save `<p>content</p>`?

Answer (score 4):

The element's name is not `content`, it is `encoded`; `content:` is the "namespace prefix", bound at the top of the document to the namespace identifier `"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"`.

Therefore, you need to use [the `->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) to select the right namespace:

```
echo $item->children('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/')->encoded;
```

(Obviously, you would probably put that namespace identifier into a variable or constant somewhere to avoid pasting it every time you need it.)

Note that I've used `echo` here, rather than `var_dump`; `var_dump` doesn't cope with SimpleXML very well (or vice versa?) and among other things will make it look like the CDATA content is missing. `echo`, on the other hand, implicitly casts to string to get the content, which works fine. In real code, you're likely to want to get that string content explicitly, like this:

```
$encoded_content = (string) $item->children('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/')->encoded;
```